# excel vba shift cells without date format

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set imported into excel with 645,000 rows. Sometimes the names are inserted into the columns with dates when the name should all be in one cell. Is there any way to write a vba code that would copy the name into the cell and shift the other data over?[screenshot of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weymC.png) I would like to move John into the cell with Doe and shift the rest of the data one cell to the left

Comment: While this is not your first post to this site, allow me to remind you that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) once again. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: In addition to the comment from Ralph, I think if you provide the data you imported it might be easier to fix the import to avoid the problem you got.